# SAS: How to use results from one table to search and count based on matches in a second table

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I'm attempting to put together a list of people and the number of times a claim is submitted in a unique combination.

Table A structure is setup like this:

```
     PERSON_ID    CLAIM_ID   
     123456       A123C   
     123456       Z321C   
     123456       B123C   
     111111       A123C   
     111111       Z321C
```

Table B structure is setup like this:

```
     PERSON_ID    CLAIM_1    CLAIM_2    CLAIM_3   
     123456       A123C      Z321C      B123C   
     123456       A123C      B123C   
     123456       B123C   
     111111       A123C      Z321C   
     111111       A321C
```

The results I need to produce is like this:

```
     PERSON_ID    CLAIM_ID    NUM_TIMES_CLAIMED   
     123456       A123C         2   
     123456       Z321C         1   
     123456       B123C         3   
     111111       A123C         1   
     111111       Z321C         2
```

I can do this in MSAccess using loops with open recordsets and I've tried researching on how to open a SAS recordset to loop through (macros) it but I can't seem to sort out how to implement it correctly.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
The steps that I think I have to take are:

Step 1 - Isoloate a single persons distinct list of CLAIM_IDs
Step 2 - For each CLAIM_ID, scan across 25 variables to find a match
Step 3 - Count each time a match is found
Step 4 - Save observation (PERSON_ID, CLAIM_ID, NUM_TIMES_CLAIMED)

From VBA to SAS I can't seem to isolate the single persons distinct list of claims and loop through them while looping through each of the 25 variables in TABLE B

Here's what I use to evaluate if one claim is billed with another which is what I think I need to automate somehow:

```
data LOCALPC.SEL_ASMT_DEL;
  SET LOCALPC.FY2014_CC_FINAL;
    ARRAY FSC{25} $ FSC1-FSC25;
    DO I = 1 TO 25;
        IF FIND (FSC{I},'A123A') THEN 
            DO N = I+11 TO 25;
                IF FIND (FSC{J},'Z321A') THEN
                    OUTPUT;
            END;
    END;
RUN;
```

Comment: How is Table 1 related to Table 2?

Comment: Table 1 is related to Table 2 by PERSON_ID

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would ever use loops to answer a straight forward join. Now it would be easier if you first convert table B to a more normalized form.

First get your sample data into datasets:

```
data A ;
length PERSON_ID CLAIM_ID $10 ;
input PERSON_ID    CLAIM_ID   ;
cards;
123456       A123C   
123456       Z321C   
123456       B123C   
111111       A123C   
111111       Z321C   
;;;;
data B ;
length PERSON_ID CLAIM_1 - CLAIM_3 $10 ;
input PERSON_ID    CLAIM_1-CLAIM_3   ;
cards;
123456       A123C      Z321C      B123C   
123456       A123C      B123C   .
123456       B123C . .  
111111       A123C      Z321C   .
111111       A321C ..
;;;;
```

Then just join the tables and count the number of matching rows.

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as 
    select a.*,count(*) as num_times_claimed
    from a 
    left join b
    on a.person_id = b.person_id 
    and (a.claim_id = b.claim_1
      or a.claim_id = b.claim_2
      or a.claim_id = b.claim_3
         )
    group by 1,2
    order by 1,2
  ;
quit;
proc print; run;
```

Results:

```
   PERSON_
     ID       CLAIM_ID    num_times_claimed

   111111      A123C          1
   111111      Z321C          1
   123456      A123C          2
   123456      B123C          3
   123456      Z321C          1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't think I described by datasets correctly though. Table A contains a distinct list  of people and claims they submit (~1m observations). Table B contains a distinct list of people and what claims were billed at a single time (~450m observations). The people have the ability to submit up to 25 different claims at one time.  The average number of distinct combinations per person is 150 with the average number of distinct claim ids at 34. What I'm trying to achieve is to count the number of times a claim is billed in a distinct combination of claims.

Comment: That sounds like the number this code generates. So if someone in A has no bills in B then the count would be 0. Otherwise the count is the number of observations in B.  Only difference might be if the same claim_id appeared twice on the same record in B. This query would count that only once.

Comment: You're right! I didn't see it at first because I thought it was such a complicated problem. Thank you! - EDIT: Can't complain with these results. VBA took ~6 hours...  NOTE: Table SUMMARY created, with 1914607 rows and 3 columns.   NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           2:59.99
      cpu time            1:54.16

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the result from just from 'Table A' assuming all the claims are inserted in Table A in the form of rows and there are duplicated claims for a person_id.

```
SELECT  PERSON_ID, CLAIM_ID, COUNT(1)
FROM    [TABLE A] A
GROUP BY PERSON_ID, CLAIM_ID
```

If not, then please describe your table structures and relations between them so that we could help you.

Comment: Table A contains a distinct list of people and claims they submit (~1m observations). Table B contains a distinct list of people and what claims were billed at a single time (~450m observations). The people have the ability to submit up to 25 different claims at one time. The average number of distinct combinations per person is 150 with the average number of distinct claim ids at 34.